# How to make my external HDD recognized as removable device?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, windows-11, eject

I have an external HDD when I plug it to my pc (Windows 11) it works fine, but the problem is that windows treat it as internal (not removable device) so I can't eject it safely

[image: 1]

So **my question is** how to convert the type from basic to removable disk? When I google it, they say open the property and locate the policy tap, but I can see it for disk 1

[image: 2]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does it happen only with this one disk? Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here are my ideas:

You could try formatting it. I don't know if this works, but you could try. The only problem is, is that it would wipe the whole drive.

If its an external, it would be by USB. So to eject it safely you could shutdown the PC, just so nothing is using it. But you might not want to do that, as restarting just to take out a device isn't really the most ideal thing to do.

My last suggestion is that if you cannot find any help here, go to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/ and maybe try talking to an agent (live chat) about this.